# Mysql Selecting from multiple tables

Tags: mysql, innodb, select

I have the following tables:

```
-- Table structure for table `Operator`
--

CREATE TABLE Operator (
  OperatorID int(11) NOT NULL,
  Name varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  Street varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  Town varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  Postcode varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  Email varchar(35) NOT NULL,
  Phone varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (OperatorID)
) 

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `Route`
--

CREATE TABLE Route (
  RouteNumber varchar(5) NOT NULL,
  Frequency int(11) NOT NULL,
  Start varchar(5) NOT NULL,
  Destination varchar(5) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (RouteNumber)
) 

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `RouteOperators`
--

CREATE TABLE RouteOperators (
  RouteNumber varchar(5) NOT NULL,
  OperatorID int(11) NOT NULL,
  Proportion int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (RouteNumber, OperatorID)
)
```

I'm attempting to retrieve the phone numbers and emails of operators who serve bus stop 7628 (i.e Start or Destination = 7628) with the following query:

```
SELECT Phone,Email FROM Operator, Route, RouteOperators 
WHERE (Route.Start = 7628 OR Route.Destination = 7628) 
AND RouteOperators.RouteNumber = Route.RouteNumber 
AND Operator.OperatorID = RouteOperators.RouteNumber
```

The query doesn't return anything, although there are also no errors. Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably meant `AND Operator.OperatorID = RouteOperators.OperatorID`

I'd suggest using the `JOIN...ON (...)` syntax, it makes the query more readable.

```
SELECT o.Phone,o.Email 
FROM Route r 
INNER JOIN RouteOperators ro 
    ON r.RouteNumber = ro.RouteNumber 
INNER JOIN Operator o 
    ON ro.OperatorID = o.OperatorID 
WHERE Route.Start = 7628 
OR Route.Destination = 7628
```

You might also want to consider introducing foreign key constraints.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
AND Operator.OperatorID = RouteOperators.RouteNumber
```

you should be joining on

```
AND Operator.OperatorID = RouteOperators.OperatorID
```

Learn to use `JOIN ... USING(...)`. You also get a lot of result rows unless you `GROUP BY`.